# how to make a damage curve not end abrubtly

Tags: game-design, combat

I want this because I am making a game where you control a bunch of units, and each of them have different health and weapons. I want to make a weapon that deals damage to everybody on the enemy team, but to prevent spamming that unit it deals a specific damage type and each unit can only take a certain amount of damage from that unit every second.

Some things I have considered is having it be linear up until the cap, but that feels like the sudden stoppage of damage these units would do would be too abrupt. I have also considered doing something logarithmic with a hard cap.

My question is what other options are there that would make sense in this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) curve, like these computationally cheap [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290768/computationally-simple-sigmoid).

If you want a smooth approach to zero with no upper limit, use [tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent).